# animateWithDuration jumps (sometimes) to final position without animation

Tags: ios, swift, animation, dispatch-async

(1)
When I click on an annotation/pin my animation works fine. A tableview slides up. When I click on the map (didDeselectAnnotationView) the tableview jumps to the final position.
BUT: When I click on a cell (didSelectRowAtIndexPath) the animation slides perfectly down.

So what is the different between clicking on the map and clicking on tableViewCell? They both use the same function.

(2)
Another point:
In my tableView I'm loading content in my cells. When I try to set an image, the image appears correctly, but kill all animations. After that every up/down-animation is jumping.

Sooo I'm confused. There are no errors. I read: When animateWithDuration has a conflict or there are UI-actions at the same time, animateWithDuration jumps. Okay. But how can I handle that? Has somebody a tutorial or some general tips? I don't know where to search for my mistakes.

I tried a little bit with dispatch_asycn but nothing work.

Thank for help and sorry when the english isn't perfect :)

Some code:
(1) The animation:

```
 func animateAllInformationAboutSingleDevice(up: Bool) {
    //  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    if up {
        self.animationNSLayoutConstraint.constant += CGFloat(255)
    } else {
        self.animationNSLayoutConstraint.constant -= CGFloat(255)
    }

    UIView.animateWithDuration(Constants.animationTime, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.tableViewController.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: {
            (value: Bool) in
            self.tableViewController.reloadData()
    })

    //  })
}
```

The delete function:

```
 func deleteAllInformationAboutVehicle(annotation: MKAnnotation) {

    if let carAnnotation = annotation as? CarAnnotation {

        if carAnnotation.itemId != "" {
            setImageToDefaultImage()
            //dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.animateInformationScreen(false)
            //})

        }
    }
}
```

(2)
setting the image in tableView:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            cell.carImage?.clipsToBounds = true

            if let image = globalCurrentImageOfCar {

                cell.carImage.image = GUITools.cropToBounds(image)

            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

For your first issue, try calling `self.tableViewController.layoutIfNeeded()` before you change your constraint constants and run the animation block.

It could be the case that the view hasn't been laid out to it's previous position before trying to animate to its new one.

Comment: i called self.tableViewController.layoutIfNeeded() in viewDidAppear() alternativ in viewDidLoad() but both doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

okay strange thing...

In my `func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, didDeselectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView) {` it is quite import to call `tableViewController.reloadDate()`

Unfortunately I don't know why. 
I think, every function/code or whatever, have to call reloadData before the animation begins. If somebody know, please give a comment. @Christopher Kevin Howell: thanks for help